# Can't assign a keyboard shortcut to a certain bash commands using xfce-keyboard-settings in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, xfce

Can't assign a keyboard shortcut to certain bash commands using xfce-keyboard-settings in Linux Mint

I'm using Linux Mint 14 Nadia

I use xfce-keyboard-settings to assign keyboard shortcuts to commands like

```
$ feh -ZF ~/Pictures
```

Feh is a command line image viewer and I can assign keyboard shortcuts to it.  But it doesn't seem to work for commands like

```
$ mv ~/feh_slideshow_list1 ~/feh_list2
```

Comment: You want to assign a keyboard shortcut to a specific `mv` command? Why? What is it you are _really_ trying to do?

Comment: Feh generates a text file with a list of all the photos in the slideshow and by default it give it a long name like feh_005849_000001_filelist and puts it in the home directory.  I have shortcuts set up to do a slideshow using a textfile whose name doesn't change.  I frequently move the file named feh_005849_000001_filelist (or whatever it happens to be) into a different folder and name it "feh".

Comment: I don't know why the specific command fails. Have you tried using a script or an alias instead? If you don't know how I can post an answer to that effect. I am not doing so because I don't have xfce installed so I can't test.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for your interest.  Using a script works.

Comment: You're welcome. remember to accept your answer as soon as the time limit passes so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.  I created a script with my move command in it and I am able to assign a keyboard shortcut to the script.

```
#! /bin/bash

mv ~/feh_slideshow_list1 ~/feh_list2
```